# Can I use sed/awk/etc to replace parts of a file with text from stdin?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, string, replace

I have a configuration script which does basically this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source vars.sh

cat >foo.output <<EOF
# some static stuff (many lines...)
variable_bit=($SOME_VAR, $SOME_OTHER_VAR, ...)
# some more static stuff (many lines...)
EOF
```

It would be nicer to have some other file, call it `foo.output.template`, which looked like this

```
# some static stuff (many lines...)
VARIABLE_BIT
# some more static stuff (many lines...)
```

Then, my configuration script could do something like this

```
sed 's/VARIABLE_BIT/<<STDIN>>/' foo.output.template >foo.output <<EOF
variable_bit=($SOME_VAR, $SOME_OTHER_VAR, ...)
EOF
```

This won't work, and I don't know if `sed` can do this, but the intention is that it

- reads foo.output.template
- matches `VARIABLE_BIT`
- replaces this with whatever is in stdin
- then pipes to foo.output

Can `sed`, `awk`, or some other common *nix utility do this easily?

Comment: Maybe `(read -r line; sed "s/VARIABLE_BIT/$line/" ... ) << ...`

Comment: I'm sure this must be a duplicate - you can do something like `cat foo | sed -e '/VARIABLE_BIT/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' foo.output.template > foo.output`

Comment: @steeldriver That looks promising, can you please unpack what you wrote?

Comment: @spraff I have outlined an answer below

Answer (score 4):

At least if you have GNU `sed`, then given

```
$ cat foo.output.template
# some static stuff (many lines...)
VARIABLE_BIT
# some more static stuff (many lines...)
```

and

```
$ cat bar
hello
hello
```

then you can match `VARIABLE_BIT`, read and insert the contents of `bar`, then delete `VARIABLE_BIT`:

```
$ cat bar | sed '/^VARIABLE_BIT/{
r /dev/stdin
d
}' foo.output.template
# some static stuff (many lines...)
hello
hello
# some more static stuff (many lines...)
```

You can make it into a one-liner if you are careful to avoid the `d` being interpreted as part of the filename

```
cat bar | sed -e '/^VARIABLE_BIT/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' foo.output.template
```

Redirect to an output file in the usual way i.e. `> foo.output`

---

Note: I have used `cat bar` just to illustrate standard input; if you really want to use a *file* for the replacement text, then you can do that directly i.e.

```
sed -e '/^VARIABLE_BIT/{r bar' -e 'd;}' foo.output.template > foo.output
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you split your template into two files, one before the variable part and one after it? The shell can then concatenate them like this:

```
( cat foo.output.template.before; cat ; cat foo.output.template.after; ) >foo.output
```

Comment: That would be the easy hack, I'm curious as to whether there's a neat all-in-one solution.

Comment: If there are no backspace (`\b`) characters in your input, then here you are: `sed -e "s/VARIABLE_BIT/$(tr '\n' '\b' | sed 's/.$//')/" foo.output.template  | tr '\b' '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat before.input - after.input >output <<EOF
whatever $FOO $BAR
EOF
```